# Is it possible to use Google Prompt for my own application?

Tags: android, google-account

Google has introduced [Google Prompt](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6361026) as a new way to log in with two factor authentication, without having to install any additional app on an android device. Is there a way to use this feature for my own application, without installing an app ? Pushing a custom message to my phone with a simple yes/no reply ?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment there is no API for this, and Google has not announced any such plans. You will need to look into another solution for this, perhaps something along the lines of [Authy Push Authentications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/push-authentications).

Comment: Okta Verify and Duo Security are two other products in this area.

Comment: Is it the same now? Still no API available? any idea?

Comment: Looked earlier this week - this still seems to be the case.